# convert a string JSON into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following string

```
"[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
   {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    "completed": false
  }
]"
```

How can i convert this string into a JSON?

Comment: why does `JSON.parse` not work?

Comment: It is already JSON. Are you asking how to parse the JSON as JS array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: @FelixKling yes, to make the JSON into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()` and replace the starting and ending `"` with backticks

```
JSON.parse(`[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
   {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    "completed": false
  }
]`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use JSON.parse()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
JSON.parse(str)
```